# Metapost text labels inside MPinclusions

Tags: context-mkiv, metapost

For some reason code like this:

```
\startMPinclusions
    picture p;
    p := image(
        draw btex 123 etex;
    );
\stopMPinclusions
\startMPcode
    draw p;
\stopMPcode
```

Causes error `Equation cannot be performed (color=vacuous)...` (I actually tried to report this as a [bug](http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=989), but, likely, did something wrong).

Is there any workaround for this, that does not require moving labels to MPcode?

Comment: It is better to report such bugs on the context mailing list rather than on the luatex bug tracker. The bug appears to be on line 421 of `mlib-lua.lua`: it should read `local box = textexts and textexts[n]`. That gets rid of the error message, but there is no text displayed. I'll have to look more carefully as to what is happening. The best bet is to report it to the context mailing list

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to figure out how to report it there then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug. As a work around, you can use:

```
\startuseMPgraphic{picp}
    picture p;
    p := image(
        draw  btex 123 etex;
    );
\stopuseMPgraphic
\starttext
\startMPcode
    \includeMPgraphic{picp}
    draw p;
\stopMPcode
\stoptext
```

Comment: It works, thank you! It looks roughly equivalent to:

    \startMPinclusions
        def q = 
            picture p;
            p := image(
                draw btex 123 etex;
            );
        enddef;
    \stopMPinclusions
    \startMPcode
        q;
        draw p;
    \stopMPcode

if I still want to use MPinclusions

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's another working solution:

```
\startMPinclusions
    vardef p = 
        image(
            draw btex 123 etex;
        )
    enddef;
\stopMPinclusions
\startMPcode
    draw p;
\stopMPcode
```

This way I don't even have to do anything with *MPcode